# Check Text Mode when Typing text MapInfo

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

I'm writing a code MapBasic
How do I know text mode when I add text to Map.

Can help me!, check cursor texting mode

Comment: I use code:
MenuItemInfoByHandler(M_TOOLS_TEXT,MENUITEM_INFO_CHECKED), works well with MapInfo 11.5, but get an error when using MapInfo 10. Then call automatic when the menu item or button change.Have any handler or procedure?

Comment: error when using MapInfo 10:

(textmode.mb:21) Invalid menu item handler in call to MenuItemInfoByHandler.

Comment: I wite a code: Run a handler automatically when click button Text in standard ButtonPad, and disable menu item shortcut code ex Ctrl+T